# When does claims transformation occur when using a custom IClaimsTransformer?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, claims-based-identity

I am using ASP.NET Core and a custom `IClaimsTransformer` which is registered during `Configure` in my `Startup` class with the `ClaimsTransformationMiddleware`. I was under the impression that claims were added and possibly transformed when the user was first signed in (similar to what I see in the Google authentication middleware).

I have found on GitHub the [ClaimsTransformationMiddleware](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/22d2fe99c6fd9806b36025399a217a3a8b4e50f4/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication/ClaimsTransformationMiddleware.cs#L48) that invokes a custom claims transformer that has been registered via `UseClaimsTransformation`.

Without signing out and in again, I am able to change the values of the claim when I, for example, hard code a claim value and recompile the application. Said another way, claims are updated when:

1. I start the app and sign in, then view a page that displays the claims
2. I make a code change to set a different value in the transformer
3. I restart the app and refresh the page

Further, if I change the value of the claim in the transformer to say, `DateTime.Now.Millisecond.ToString()` the value is changed on each page request without recompiling the app.

This seems to infer that the custom transformation happens on each request, rather than on sign in. Is that correct?

Is there a way to register the transformation in a way that only happens on login? There are no other options in `ClaimsTranformationOptions`.

Comment: you can change the principal on sign in by deriving from UserClaimsPrincipalFactory

Comment: Thanks @EricB, can I assume the above assumption is correct then?